# How to change language of website if url ends with "lang=fr"

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, url

Let's say I have a page with the URL `www.page.com/default.aspx?lang=fr`.

Is there a way to change the content's language with JavaScript by looking at the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible, but potentially complex and definitely not advisable. Besides needing a script that dynamically changes the text of each element on the page, you'd need to provide the french resources on the client in the first place, as well as all other languages you intend to support. For everything but the most simple pages this would be a huge and unmaintainable mess.

This is better done on the server using Resources:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I am new to javascript ,but I think it's not so difficult to solve this question:

```
var specifyLang='yourLang';//define your page language 
var temp=location.protocol+'//'+location.host+location.pathname+'?lang='+specifyLang;//cpmplete the new URL
location=temp;
location.reload(true);//refresh the page from server
```

maybe it's not prefect ,but solve your problem at least...